# Name for point sets with trivial optimal Hamilton cycle

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, terminology

**Question:**

is there an established name for sets of $n$ points in the euclidean plane whose shortest Hamilton cycles consists of the $n$ pairs of points having the $n$ smallest distances?

Names for symmetric weighted graphs with the analogous property are also appreciated.

Comment: for a "flat" trapezoid like the with corners at (-2,0) (2,0) (1,1)(-1,1) the longest edge isn't a diagonal and thus wouldn't be a pointset I'm (currently) interested in. One can easily proof that the geometric angle defined by two adjacent tour edges must be greater than 60°, but that criterion isn't sufficient.